# Return a promised value to variable in angular.extend()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the example below, how can I set myVar to a value return from an async service method

```
angular.extend(this, {
    myVar: (function() {
        getVal();
    })()
});

function getVal() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    MyFactory.Get()
        .then(function (resp) {
            d.resolve(resp.data);
        });
    return d.promise; // myVar should equal resp.data
};
```

I think I'm showing my lack of understanding of promises/deferral, so advice would be great.

Comment: What does the following snippet returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since myVar is a variable you could set it from anywhere in the controller. In the initialization you can assign it to a fallback value or set it undefined. And set it after the async call is success.

```
angular.extend(vm, {
    myVar: 'fallback'
});
```

or:

```
angular.extend(vm, {
});
```

Then:
in the controller:

```
getVar();
function getVar() {
    getVal().then(function(data){
        vm.myVar = data;
    });
}

function getVal() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    MyFactory.Get()
        .then(function (resp) {
            d.resolve(resp.data);
        });
    return d.promise; // myVar should equal resp.data
};
```

or more efficiently:

```
getVal();

function getVal() {
    MyFactory.Get()
        .then(function (resp) {
            vm.myVar = resp.data;
        });
};
```

changed `this` to `vm` for removing conflict with `this` keyword may throw.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - I wanted to avoid assigning anything outside extend(), just for the sake of keeping the controller clean. Pretty sure I can get it working, thanks again.

Comment: Welcome. Actually, defining everything outside extend is the way to get clean controller. If the answer helped you, please upvote and accept it. So that similar questions get fast answers.